# Проверка данных формы

Tags: java, html, spring, mvc, thymeleaf

отправляю форму из html страницы, и хочу произвести обработку данных, которые отправились и в случае ошибки вывести сообщение о ней(конкретно что не так).
Я видел примеры разметки POJO классов через аннотации(пример @NotEmpty @NotNull и т д) **такое не нужно**.
Я хочу в отдельных функциях делать проверку и возвращать кастомную ошибку.
Можете пожалуйста покидать примеров как это можно сделать или статей.
**Если я объяснил непонятно(что бывает даволько часто), то вот еще формулировка:** как мне решить задачу например пользователь отправляет форму и если значения `date` , `time` и `teacherName` уже записаны в одной строке в базе данных(данные из формы и бд совпадают), то возвращаем ошибку "у {teacherName} уже пара в {date} {time}" и в БД не записывать. 
Вот форма на всякий случай:

```
<form name="search-theme-form" action="#" th:action="@{/admin/add}" id="search-theme-form"
          th:object="${schedule}" method='POST'>
        <td>
            <select id="dropdown_faculty" th:field="*{facultyName}">
                <option th:text="${choosenFaculty}" th:value="${choosenFaculty}"></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="dropdown_specialty" th:field="*{specialtyName}">
                <option th:text="${choosenSpecialty}" th:value="${choosenSpecialty}"></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="dropdown_group" th:field="*{groupName}">
                <option th:text="${choosenGroup}" th:value="${choosenGroup}"></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="dropdown_date" th:field="*{date}">
                <option th:text="${choosenDate}" th:value="${choosenDate}"></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select th:field="*{time}">
                <option value="">Не выбран</option>
                <option th:each="time : ${timeAll}"
                        th:value="${time.lessonTimeStart +'--'+time.lessonTimeEnd}"
                        th:utext="${time.lessonTimeStart +'--'+time.lessonTimeEnd}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select th:field="*{subjectName}">
                <option value="">Не выбран</option>
                <option th:each="subject : ${subjectAll}"
                        th:value="${subject.subjectName}"
                        th:utext="${subject.subjectName}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select th:field="*{teacherName}">
                <option value="">Не выбран</option>
                <option th:each="teacher : ${teacherAll}"
                        th:value="${teacher.teacherName}"
                        th:utext="${teacher.teacherName}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select th:field="*{classroomName}">
                <option value="">Не выбран</option>
                <option th:each="classroom : ${classroomAll}"
                        th:value="${classroom.classroomNumber}"
                        th:utext="${classroom.classroomNumber}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select th:field="*{lessonType}">
                <option value="">Не выбран</option>
                <option th:each="lessonT : ${lessonTypeAll}"
                        th:value="${lessonT.lessonType}"
                        th:utext="${lessonT.lessonType}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
    </form>
```

POJO:

```
        @Entity
    @Table(name = "testscheduletable")
    public class TestScheduleTable implements Comparable<TestScheduleTable> {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        @NotNull
        private String facultyName;
        @NotNull
        private String specialtyName;
        @NotNull
        private String groupName;
        @NotNull
        private String subjectName;
        @NotNull
        private String teacherName;
        @NotNull
        private String classroomName;
        @NotNull
        private String lessonType;
        @NotNull
        private String time;
        @NotNull
        private String date;
        //дальше конструкторы, геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

Comment: Для ответа на вопрос требуется указать, что было сделано при попытке решения задачи и какие ошибки возникали.

Comment: Не могли бы вы предоставить код своего контроллера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можете создать кастомную ошибку по типу

```
public class SomeCustomException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final String MESSAGE = "у %s уже есть пара в %s %s";

    public SomeCustomException(String teacherName, String date, String time) {
        super(String.format(MESSAGE, teacherName, date, time));
    }
}
```

Можно словить `SomeCustomException` используя аннотациyю `ExceptionHandler(SomeCustomException.class)` с помощью функции в контроллере - например

```
    @ExceptionHandler(SomeCustomException.class)
    protected String handleEntityNotFound(SomeCustomException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
```

Или создать отдельный класс для всех контроллеров

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(SomeCustomException.class)
    protected String handleEntityNotFound(SomeCustomException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

[Вот еще очень хороший пост про Error Handling](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling)